# how to check a condition in object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, map-function

I am trying to use an array map for checking if same username and password exist in an object array

```
database.map((obj)=>{
  if(values.name  === obj.name && values.password===obj.password){
    console.log("login success");
  } else {
    console.log("login Failed");
  }
});
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: What do you mean? On what are you using an array map, and what do you want to know?

Comment: please specify what do you want to do, what you have tried, expected and actual result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You may use find for conditions:**

```
const result = database.find((val)=> {
return val.name === obj.name && val.password === obj.password;
})

if(result){
console.log("login success");
}
else{
console.log("login failed");
}
```

Comment: You mean `find()`, right?  filter will always return an array, so result will always be truthy.

Comment: I was about to write that. That's why I checked the truthy value of length.

Comment: @danh You are right!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this is the answer you are looking for, but if you want to check data you should use filter instead of map. Map is to create a new array (with the same amount of elements).

```
const matches = database.filter(o => o.name === values.name && o.password === values.password);
```

That will return a new array if the condition is met.
You can check is there is any.

```
if (matches.length) {
  console.log("login success");
} else {
  console.log("login Failed");
}
```

Comment: This is the right way to use `filter()`, but `find()` is a better choice here (also), since the check is only for the existence of an object matching the condition.  With find(), once one is found, you stop looking.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about that one. Handy.

Answer (score 0):

```
let database = [{ name: 'Krishna', password: 'Krishna@123' }, { name: 'Radhe', password: 'Radhe@123' }];
let values = { name: 'Radhe', password: 'Radhe@123' };
let status=database.some(obj=>obj.name===values.name && obj.password===values.password);
console.log(status==true?"Login Success":"Login Failed");
```